# JS/jQuery TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've been scratching my head on this for 2 days, pretty sure I'm just missing something simple but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not working.

I'm trying to use the script below on my WordPress site to disable specific dates within a datepicker field in a ContactForm7 form.

I can load the script in jsfiddle with a simple input field using the same id and it works perfectly...but when I add it to my site the dates aren't disabled, and there's an error in the JS error console that says "jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function"

I've added it in my `header.php` file, just below the `wp_head()` call and just above the `</head>` tag. I've assigned my datepicker field with the id of `dpick` like the script uses.

I read that this error is commonly caused when using the `$` symbol because it can conflict with other jQuery scripts within WordPress...so they suggested replacing `$` with `jQuery` instead (which I've done in the script below)...but I'm still getting the error

```
var unavailableDates = ["1-9-2013", "2-9-2013", "3-9-2013", "4-9-2013", "5-9-2013"];

    function unavailable(date) {
            dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
            if (jQuery.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
                return [true, ""];
            } else {
                return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
    }

        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery( '#dpick' ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
                beforeShowDay: unavailable
        });

    });
```

Can't thank you enough for any help you can offer...this seems like such a simple thing but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it!

Comment: have you included jquery ui library to your website?

Comment: @maverickosama92 yes, I believe that's part of the `wp_head()` call...when I view the source of my page, I can see that it's calling the core jquery ui as well as a bunch of specific jquery ui modules

Comment: It looks like everything but the jQuery UI datepicker is included on your site. Might want to take a look at that. Core doesn't include datepicker automatically http://i.imgur.com/Hd9FdsL.png

Comment: @vernak2539 So it's a problem with the datepicker itself, not a problem with the script? The datepicker was included with the ContactForm7 plugin that I'm using...and it seems to be working okay for selecting dates (within the browsers that support it...I can't get the datepicker to work in Firefox/IE/Safari but it works fine in Chrome/Opera) but I just can't seem to get this date disabling script to work with it

Comment: @Iconoclast The issue is that the datepicker file is not being included and jquery doesn't have that function available to it. Hence the TypeError. The reason it works in chrome/opera is because the input type is "date" which they supports at the moment, but FF/IE/Safari don't, so that's why you're seeing that.

Comment: @vernak2539 okay, thank you! I updated my original post to include all of my jQuery library references, is the datepicker not in one of these? I see someone in another question says the datepicker is in this one: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` but shouldn't that also be included with the very first reference in the list?

Comment: @Iconoclast the datepicker isn't one of these. There should be another file like jquery.ui.datepicker.js for datepicker to be enabled.

Comment: @vernak2539 what tool/prohgram generated the image you posted at  i.imgur.com/Hd9FdsL.png ??  looks to be very handy. Is that developer tools within Chrome?

Comment: @zipzit I am on a Mac, so I used cmd+shift+4, which will then turn your cursor into a selection tool. you can then click and drag what you want to save as an image. alternatively, cmd+shift+3 will take a screenshot of your entire screen

Comment: @vernak2539  Wow did we mis-communicate that!  I full understand how to get a screen capture.  What I'm trying to figure out what tool are you taking a screen capture of.  Is that Chrome developer tools console, is that some sort of IDE (Integrated Development Environment)?  What program are we looking at?  Where did the content of the image come from?

Comment: @zipzit haha sorry about that. yeah it's chrome's devtools. same thing can be accomplished with firebug or firefox's devtools

Answer (score 21):

The are several reasons for this error:

1. The jquery.ui is used before jquery.
2. The $ is used by another library.
3. The jquery lib that is referenced locally(wordpress) has different version from that using jquery.ui.
4. When the right library and version is referenced the browser cache must be cleared.

Comment: It looks like jQuery is loaded before jQueryUI, so that should be okay. I'm not using $ in the script, so that should be okay. According to my WP dashboard everything is up to date so I don't think it's because of different jQuery versions...

Comment: The jquery.ui is used before jquery. This is the most common reason

Comment: I am getting the same error but due to "The $ is used by another library" ho do i resolve this???

Comment: You may use the immediate function pattern to encapsulate '$'. (function($){...})(your-jQuery-version-here);
Search for widget example.

Comment: for me second point was creating issue just resolved by changing that to some other variable

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem. In my case I had two jQuery script references on my main page (`_Layout.cshtml` in ASP.NET MVC). I added 1 reference to jQuery at the top but there was 1 at the bottom of the page that I didn't notice... In Firebug this is what I saw:

[image]

So as you can see, jQuery UI was sitting in the middle of the conflict! :D This took me some time to figure out.

Comment: help me alot...so you remove the one after `jquery-ui-1.10.3.js`

Answer (score 3):

check if all files are loaded.Should have 200 ok status.

Comment: Ok, I'm hours looking for this error, and then ONE css file was not loaded... Your answer did me look Fidller, and now is everything working fine...

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, for conflicting jquery codes -

```
  <script>  
  $.noConflict();  //Not to conflict with other scripts
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat:"yyyy-mm-dd",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  maxDate: "+0D"
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but may be It can help other people:

The best practice to include js in wordpress is to do it using It's queuing function in the php template:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
```

(seen [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/))

It allows to declare the dependencies of your script, in this case, the jquery datepicker. You can check de built-in scripts that wordpress can provide in:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#default-scripts-included-and-registered-by-wordpress

Wordpress provide dependencies specifically for jquery datepicker so you could include your script with something like:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', 'mypath' . '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ), 1.7, true);
```

Note that if you only declare the jquery dependency you'll get an error like

> 'jQuery.datepicker(...) is not a function'

since the datepicker functions are not included in the base wordpres jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with wordpress so I might be out of line trying to help. I have used pickadate though.

In the past I've gotten this error before

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

It's usually occurs because I didn't load the js files in the right order. Looking in developer tools on your site I don't see where the pickadate plugin is even loaded. I would check (if you haven't yet) to make sure the plugin is being loaded as well as being loaded in the right order.

Comment: do you know what reference I need to use to be able to use the datepicker? I tried but it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue. I had this same issue and it was because of including jquery.min.js along with jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery-ui.js. So by removing jquery.min.js my issue of TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function got resolved. Hope it helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Okay , I have the same problem a while ago and the solution to the problem is just to add to include the `jquery.ui.datepicker.js` it is included in the jquery package. However i am still wondering why I have to include this because Im using `jquery.ui` before and the `jquery.ui.custom` or simply the jquery js file will do the `.datepicker()` function for me.

Anyway it's still nice it now working . Hope this helps.

Comment: hey can you give me the cdn of this. Can't find

Answer (score 0):

I moved all scripts from footer to head then things started to work propertly

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but only on firefox browser. We are using require to load the js files. I had following lines in my javascript.

```
require(['jquery', 'jqueryui'], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form1").validationEngine({ bindButtons: $(".bindButton") });

        $("#txtBidDate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});
        $("#txtInstDate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});
    });
```

Require loads js files asynchroulsy and the order is not gauranteed unless you define shim config or if your js files are all loaded as AMD. In our case, jquery was loaded after jquery-ui. We defined in main.js for require that jquery-ui has dependency on jquery. This fixed it for us