# jQuery ui datepicker not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here's my datepicker which isn't working in Firefox

```
  <div class="input-append datepicker">
              <?php if($_REQUEST["date"]){ ?>
                <input id="filter-date" size="16" type="date" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["date"];?>"/>
              <?php } else { ?>
                <input id="filter-date" size="16" type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"/>
              <?php } ?>
    </div>

$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

What can I do to fix this?

**UPDATE**

Here's how Firefox renders it.

[image]

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Here are the scripts that I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../lodash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../datatables.responsive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../dom-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well you have to give the inputs the class name = to datepicker. Second I don't know if this is just incomplete code but you also need to wrap that in script tags as well as a `jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{

});`

Comment: This could answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382788/js-jquery-typeerror-jquery-datepicker-is-not-a-function

Comment: Changing name=datepicker wont help because jQuery is targeting the class and not the name

Comment: Maybe unrelated but is there any reason you are loading (what looks like) two versions of the jQuery library? `<script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

Answer (score 12):

Paulie,
You should use this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Include/JS/jquery-ui-min.js"></script>
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#filter-date").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
            });
        });
</script>
```

You need to apply datepicker to an input control of type `text`.
So try this my making these changes in your code.

```
<div class="input-append datepicker">
  <?php if($_REQUEST["date"]){ ?>
  <input id="filter-date" size="16" type="text"
                    value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["date"];?>"/>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <input id="filter-date" size="16" type="text" 
                    value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"/>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the same as my answer?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward The key difference is including the `$.datepicker` attachment inside a `$.ready` call - without that there's little 'guarantee' your script will be run *after* the `#filter-date` element has been created in the DOM

Comment: @BrianNorth I don't think so, the main problem is that the date picker i not attached properly (as my answer), we don't have the real code so we can't know that is not already running it in dom ready; second there is the type=date (as my answer) the reason why is working on chrome

Comment: Still does not work in Firefox. But it works in Chrome now without having set the type to date.

Answer (score 3):

I start from the fact that you have included right jQuery and jQuery UI in your page.

Now your are attaching the datepicker with this selector:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

you must give your element the `datepicker` class eg:

```
<?php if($_REQUEST["date"]){ ?>
    <input id="filter-date" class="datepicker" size="16" type="text" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["date"];?>"/>
<?php } else { ?>
    <input id="filter-date" class="datepicker" size="16" type="text" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"/>
<?php } ?>
```

or bind your datepicker with id selector like:

```
$('#filter-date').datepicker();
```

PS: I suggest you to don't use `type="date"` or Chrome will render the datepicker twice (its behaviour and plugin).

Comment: Will using id="filter-date" twice cause any conflicts ?

Comment: As I can see from the code the input element is created in a condition, so only one element at time will be exist

Comment: Check the console for errors and you provide your HTML markup (not PHP) and JS code

Answer (score 3):

You use a wrong selector, it's should be `$('#divDatePicker').datepicker();`, direct to the input not parent.

Answer (score 2):

Try using something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    <?php if($_REQUEST["date"]){ ?>
    $('.datepicker').datepicker( "setDate", "<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_REQUEST['date']));?>" );
    <?php }?>
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Try

```
$('.datepicker input').datepicker();
```

If you want ot use jquery write

```
<input id="filter-date" size="16" type="text" />
```

if you use type="date" it will create confusion.

So that this targets input inside the div

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wdpPR/)

Also see this stackoverflow post
[Chrome type="date" and jquery ui date picker clashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890376/chrome-type-date-and-jquery-ui-date-picker-clashing)

Answer (score 2):

You must assign `'.datepicker'` class name to inputs

Answer (score 1):

If you use `bootstrap` date picker than -

```
  <div id="divDatePicker" class="input-append datepicker">
              <?php if($_REQUEST["date"]){ ?>
                <input id="filter-date" size="16" type="date" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["date"];?>"/>
              <?php } else { ?>
                <input id="filter-date" size="16" type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"/>
              <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

You should try to bind date-picker with element `ID` :

```
$('#divDatePicker').datepicker();
```

And also write your code in script block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#divDatePicker').datepicker();
      });
</script>
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/EmwFE/111/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter version of the HTML:

```
<div class="input-append datepicker">
    <input id="filter-date" size="16" type="date" value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST["date"]) ? $_REQUEST["date"] : date('Y-m-d')) ?>"/>
</div>
```

Call the datepicker with (address the `<input>`, not the wrapping `<div>`)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#filter-date').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: hey that still doesn't work in Firefox> Check my update and have a look at the screen shot.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ (without the PHP) with the relevant code. Or have a look at the console (press F12 in Firefox)

Comment: I added jquery & jquery UI (on the left) and for me it's working perfectly in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/5hEna/

Comment: Show us your full page (maybe some other script is interfering with the datepicker) or press F12 on your site to load the console, reload the page and have a look on the output on the console.

Comment: ok the fiddle works perfectly for me but once I put it into my actual page it doesn't work. I think my scripts are interfering with each other. I can't show you my page but let me add the list of the scripts that I am using have a look and see if you can find a problem.

Comment: Why do you include jQuery two times? jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery.min.js It would really help a lot if you look at the console

Comment: I've removed those two entries and added a link to this instead: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js. The error I am getting on my console from jquery is TypeError:d.browser is undefined.

Comment: .browser has been removed from JQuery 1.9. So either take a version of JQuery below 1.9 (maybe some other scripts will stop working then when they rely on a newer version of jQuery) or remove the script which is accessing .browser

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue in some of the browsers because of the z-index which is assigned to the date picker ui. I used a work around like shown below which did the job.

```
    $(".datepicker input").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",beforeShow: function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999);},0);
    }});
```

But before that, please use inspect element in mozilla to make sure the element with class .ui-datepicker is added in the dom somewhere.

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work. On inspecting the element in Firefox i can see the class=hasDatepicker for the input but it still does not come up. How can I check this: "the element with class .ui-datepicker is added in the dom somewhere?"

Comment: Depending on the browser you can search for the class name. In safari inspect element , press Command + F and type in ui-datepicker, it will get you all the elements with that class. 
Usually it gets added just after the input element or just before the </body> closing tag. 
In any case the input element getting hasDatepicker class, means that query ui is displaying and the hasDatepicker is kind of functioning like a condition for the query ui to hide the element. 
check these screenshots
[link](http://grab.by/rHKe)
[link](http://grab.by/rHKc)
@Paulie

Answer (score 0):

You can user jQuery date picker in case of Mozilla: Check the browser using $.browser.mozilla but it will not work in jQuery>1.9, so you have to use jQuery Migration as shown below:

```
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>//jQuery migration
    <script>
        if ($.browser.mozilla)
    {
        if ($('.datepicker')[0].type != 'date') $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        $(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "1900:2015",
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                defaultDate: '1900-01-01'
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Full and Final Answer For your Datepicker Problem in Firefox using html5
Answer :

```js
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.14.5/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>
```

```html
<input type="date" name="event_date" required/>
```