# date-picker is not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am currently referring to [this](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) example. i already downloaded everything but my jquery is not working .

My html code is

```
   <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input17">Date:</label>                                                         
    <div class="controls">
    <input name="date" id="date" type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Date">
    <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a>                                                             
    <div id="error_date"></div>                              
    </div>
    </div>
```

my Jquery is this.

```
     var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#date').datepicker({
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
    var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
    checkout.setValue(newDate);
  }
  checkin.hide();

}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```

please help.

Comment: what you mean with 'not working'? it is not showing? you get any exception? it is shown but broneken?

Comment: What is it showing in console?

Comment: Did you include the right javascript links?

Comment: i include the js links. the calender dosent pop out.

Comment: Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382788/js-jquery-typeerror-jquery-datepicker-is-not-a-function

Comment: see your code is working  http://jsfiddle.net/erfb5kg1/1/

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the followings:

1. First check you have added appropriate version of jquery.
2. Check that you have already added your date picker plugin after adding jquery.
3. Then you need to add you code which will initialize your date picker plugin.

If everything is proper, then check you have bind your code in [$.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). If not so, then bind your code in `$.ready` so that your plugin initialization works after every element of DOM is ready.

```js
$(function() {
  var nowTemp = new Date();
  var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

  var checkin = $('#date').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
      return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
  }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
      var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
      newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
      checkout.setValue(newDate);
    }
    checkin.hide();

  }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    checkout.hide();
  }).data('datepicker');
});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>



<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="input17">Date:</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input name="date" id="date" type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Date">
    <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a> 
    <div id="error_date"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      //initialize datepicker with some optional options
      var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
      $(element).datepicker(options);
      
      //when a user changes the date, update the view model
      ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function(event) {
             var value = valueAccessor();
             if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                 value(event.date);
             }                
      });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor)   {
        var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
         //when the view model is updated, update the widget
        if (widget) {
            widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            widget.setValue();            
        }
    }
};

var model = {
    test_date: ko.observable(new Date('2012/12/12'))
};

ko.applyBindings(model, $("#target")[0]);
```

```css
#target {
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgithub.com/Aymkdn/Datepicker-for-Bootstrap/master/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/Aymkdn/Datepicker-for-Bootstrap/master/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div id='target'>
    <input data-bind='datepicker: test_date'/>
    
    <div data-bind="text: test_date"></div>
    
    <input data-bind='datepicker: test_date'/>
</div>
```