# conflicting master and content page while using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Iam using Master and Content page in asp.net C#.. In my webapplication i'm using bootstrap.. I got the error as **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function**

If i attempt to solve the above error, the dropdown in master page is producing error as **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function**

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    (anonymous function) @ com_mst_CompanyRegistrationAdd.aspx:111
    i @ jquery.min.js:2
    fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
    ready @ jquery.min.js:2
    K @ jquery.min.js:2`

In Master Page:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
});
</script>
```

In the content page:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtEstablishedDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,               
                });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#txtRCDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtCstDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Please help me to sort out the error..

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught Type Error.I think You Are Using Jquery UI widgets.
You Need To Paste The Below Script And Link Urls Below.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This Will Sort Out The Problem

Comment: same error exists after using this code in my page.

Comment: See this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382788/js-jquery-typeerror-jquery-datepicker-is-not-a-function

Comment: The are several reasons for this error:

    The jquery.ui is used before jquery.
    The $ is used by another library.
    Try This To Sort Out